# Check if input inside label is disabled

Tags: html, css

My HTML for the form is like the following snippet:

```
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="package" value="single"/>
  <span class="label-text">Single</span>
</label>
```

To show the user, that the field is clickable, I set the CSS of the label to:

```
label {
  curser: pointer;
}
```

Now I was wondering if it is possible to check (in CSS) if the input field is disabled, and if so, set the cursor to `not-allowed`.

I tried using:

```
label:has(> input:disabled) {
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

But that didn'tt work. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: That kind of selectors `label:has(> input:disabled)`aren't supported yet ... It's a proposal for Level 4 selectors  https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:has

Comment: @DaniP Oh you're totally right... I didn't notice that no browser supports `:has` yet. Do you know another method to achieve my goal?

Comment: yeah will post an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your actual markup we can modify the target for the cursor change and make the `span` more relevant this way:

```css
label {
  position: relative;
  margin:20px;
}
label span {
  cursor:pointer;
  position: relative;
  z-index:10;
  padding-left:20px;
}
label input {
  position:absolute;
}
input[disabled]  + span {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  color:#666;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="package" value="single" />
  <span class="label-text">Single</span>
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="package" value="single" disabled/>
  <span class="label-text">Single</span>
</label>
```

---

Or if you don't want it absolute:

```css
label {
  margin: 20px;
}
label span, label input {
  cursor: pointer;
}
label input[disabled], input[disabled] + span {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  color: #666;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="package" value="single" />
  <span class="label-text">Single</span>
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="package" value="single" disabled/>
  <span class="label-text">Single</span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

your syntax is wrong, disabled should be used as an attribute:

`label:has(> input[disabled=disabled]) {
  cursor: not-allowed;
}`

Comment: It doesn't work with the disabled set as attribute either :/

Comment: make sure to use the property and value